# AngularJS - self referencing services?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm building an Angular app that will have a top-level Controller and a second-level controller. There will be n number of second-level controllers, but I want to put global-level functions someplace.  I'm doing this in a service.

I'm starting down the path of creating a single service that return an api, really, containing lots of functions (below).  The service is returning an object with two property branches that each contain a set of functions.  How can I call one of these from the other?

```
globalModule.factory('global', function($http) {

    var squares = MyApp.squares;  // this is the *only* link from Global namespace to this app

    return {
        squareMgr: {
            getSquaresEarned: function() {
                return squares.earned;
            },
            getSquaresPlaced: function() {
                return squares.placed;
            },
            setThisSquareEarned: function(value) {
                squares.earned.push(value);
            },
            setThisSquarePlaced: function(value) {
                squares.placed.push(value);
            }
        },
        missionMgr: {
            missionInfo: {},
            setMissionInfo: function(missionInfo) {
                this.missionInfo = missionInfo
            },
            complete: function(missionData) {

                log('complete called on video at ' + new Date());
                missionData.complete = true;
                log(angular.toJson(missionData));

                $http({
                    url: '/show/completeMission',
                    method: "POST",
                    data: missionData 
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    if (response.data.success === true) {

                        log('completeMission success');

                        // increment squares earned counter
                        this.squareMgr.setThisSquareEarned(missionData.id);

                        // above is an attempt to run a function contained in this 
                        // same service in a different parent property branch.
                        // how *should* I do this?
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I would try creating `squareMgr` object before the `return` statement and then just referencing it inside the returned object.

Comment: If they are essentially two services, why not make that explicit and create two services? Then one can be injected into the other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
globalModule.factory('global', function($http) {

    var glob = {
        squareMgr: {
           // ...
        },
        missionMgr: {
          foo: function() {
            glob.squareMgr.xyz(); 
          }

        }
    };

    return glob;
});
```

Comment: Doh!  i was not thinking.  Thanks!

Comment: I came searching for a more "official" way of doing so, but thanks for showing me that I'm not doing it in the wrong way.. ;)